# 社内ネットワーク(ローカルネットワーク)のみで利用可能なドメイン名称において適切な convention はある?

Tags: network, dns

社内の LAN を構築していたとして、例えば、社内のみからアクセス可能なWebサーバを立ち上げるとします。

この Webサーバーのアドレスを、ルーターが提供する DNS に登録して、社内端末から利用する際にはドメイン名の解決をしながらアクセスできるようにしたいときに、しかし、例えばこれをグローバルなドメインとして valid なものにしてしまうと、何かしら事故が起きそうだな、と思っています。

## 質問

社内のみに存在するサーバーのドメイン名を設定する際に、従った方が良い convention (規約)などはありますか?

Answer (score 1):

イントラネットで使用すべきドメインを指定する規約や予約されたドメインはありません。

イントラネットにおいても正規のドメインを使用してください。

外部から隔離するなら、例えば"intra.example.jp"のようにサブドメインで分離すればよいです。

Answer (score 0):

ぱっと思いついたのは、新しいトップレベルドメインが出来たときの名前衝突問題があります。
規約などは把握してませんが↓のような資料がありました。
https://jprs.jp/tech/material/name-collision-mitigation-05dec13-ja-1.0.pdf